# How to build as many `if then else` conditions as the `count` of an array on the fly?

Tags: php, arrays

The problem I have is the following: I have a variable number of array items, so I can not have a fix number of `if then else`. In any case, it can not exceed 50 items.

This is the main-standard body. How to build as many `if then else` conditions as the `count` of an array on the fly ?

```
$number = count($array);

    if (($a > $b) && ($a <= $b)) {
        }   else
```

Comment: There's something very wrong if you need to do this.... what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: what are `$a` and `$b` in your case?

Comment: isn't that just a loop over the array and all it's items?? You'd need to give more info what is the usecase/problem.

Comment: just a side note: the statement  if (($a > $b) && ($a <= $b)) can be shortened to if(false), which in turn can be shortened to nothing. maybe that solves your problem? ;-)

Comment: You can't dynamically add/remove if statements inside the code, however you can fix this by creating methods, etc. to call with some input, and make it process as you want it to. If you want a more specific code example, you should give us a more specific example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Switch in fact, please read : http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch ($number) {
    case 0:
        echo "a";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "b";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "c";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, as we don't precisely know what you are trying to achieve, but to answer your question *"How to build as many `if then else` conditions as the `count` of an array on the fly?"*:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,5,8,10,15);
$number = count($array);
$b = 7;   // we don't know yet what $a and $b could be

for ($i=0;$i<$number;$i++) {
   if($array[$i]>$b) {   // what ever condition you want here
       // do smth
   } else {
       // do smth else or nothing
   }
}
?>
```